# c++ trouble with string find first non of

Tags: c++, string

Hi I want to print characters from one point to other point
for example

```
string str = "what is o and o this "; //I want to print all the 
                        //characters [ O and O ]
string temp1;
int loc1, loc2;
loc1 = str.find_first_not_of('o');
loc2 = str.find_last_not_of('o');
temp1 = str.substr(loc1, loc2);
cout << temp1 << endl; //this prints out entire string
```

can anyone help me??
Thank you for all the helps!!

Comment: remove the `_not` from your function call names

Comment: then it prints o and o this

Comment: Put up the output you hope to get? Is it just `o and o`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `find_first_of/find_last_of` functions and second parameter of `substr` expects length, not position:

```
string str = "what is o and o this "; //I want to print all the 
                        //characters [ O and O ]
string temp1;
int loc1, loc2;
loc1 = str.find_first_of('o');
if( loc1 == string::npos ) return; // symbol not found
loc2 = str.find_last_of('o');
temp1 = str.substr( loc1, loc2 - loc1 + 1 );
cout << temp1 << endl; //this prints out entire string
```

Comment: ahh okay!! I got my substring wrong.. and part of my find last of Thank you very much